# Jquery on change event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

The event is not firing for some reason

```
<div id="plotSelectionBar">
    <span>Select What to plot</span>
    <select class="plotSelector" id="firstDropdown">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>                
    </select>

    <span>Select What to plot2</span>
    <select class="plotSelector" id="secondDropdown">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>                
    </select>
 </div>
```

The event handle is as follows:

```
$('.plotSelector').change(function(e)
{ if (this.id="firstDropdown)
  {
  //do something
  }
  else {//do something}
});
```

I have another event handle above this one that's firing just fine. What's going on?

Comment: You are missing a quote mark in your if statement.  Is that just a copy paste error or in the actual code?

Comment: is it typo ? if (this.id="firstDropdown) needs to be if (this.id="firstDropdown")

Comment: if($(this).attr('id')=='firstDropdown'){...}

Comment: Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/56xvbs2d/

Comment: Yes, that's a typo due to code simplification.

Comment: I found the problem and it's not what I thought it was, so I'm closing this question in favor to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871619/selecting-a-nested-element-by-id-or-class-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error and need to call document ready after that only use your element change event

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.plotSelector').change(function(e){
      if(this.id == "firstDropdown")
        alert(1)
        else
        {
          alert(2)
        }
  })
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="plotSelectionBar">
    <span>Select What to plot</span>
    <select class="plotSelector" id="firstDropdown">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>                
    </select>

    <span>Select What to plot2</span>
    <select class="plotSelector" id="secondDropdown">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>                
    </select>
 </div>
```