# Selecting a nested element by id or class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-2.0

I'm a bit confused how jquery searches through the DOM. 
Does it select from the root node, similar to XPath / selector, or from the current no matter where they are, similar to XPath // selector?

I have the following setup:

```
<body>
    <div id="contentSection">
    //A bunch of nested DIVs follow
           <div id="parentDIV">
                <span>Selector1</span>
                <select class="selector" id="first">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>                
                </select>

                <span>Selector2</span>
                <select class="selector" id="second">
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>                
                </select>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div id="someOtherDIVs> </div>
    <div id="someOtherDIVs> </div>
  </body>
```

Now if I try to select the content section first, then filter by class or id, I can attach an event handler to the select element, but if I try to query the element directly, the event handler is never attached.

For example, this works:

```
$('#contentSection').change('.plotSelector', function(e)
```

But these do not:

```
$('#first').change(function(e) ... 
$('.selector').change(function(e) ...
```

Can someone explain why? Is there a way to select from the root any element anywhere in the DOM?

Using jquery 2.1.1

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/3Lanknz7/

Comment: ..and me https://jsfiddle.net/markwill/0nunxzy5/2/

Answer (score 0):

Yes the selectors work across the DOM (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

The fiddles supplied in the comments work, have you checked your console for errors, maybe the javascript isn't running completely.

Comment: Maybe check that you're selecting correctly by, say, setting a style or something visible on the element. Also, check your JavaScript is running. The fiddle works, so it must be something trivial.

Comment: It is something trivial. The code that registers the event is called early on, before the page is fully rendered and thus the element I want to attach to does not exist. Duhh

Comment: Fixed anyway! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to select from the root any element anywhere in the
>   DOM?

So long as you start from `document.`, the standard javascript methods *all* select from the root:

- `document.getElementById('');`
- `document.getElementsByClassName('');`
- `document.getElementsByTagName('');`
- `document.querySelector('');`
- `document.querySelectorAll('');`